# How can I ignore case in a regex?

Tags: asp.net, regex, ignore-case

I have an ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator that checks file extensions. Is there a quick way I can tell it to ignore the case of the extension without having to explicitly add the upper case variants to my validation expression?

```
ValidationExpression="([^.]+[.](jpg|jpeg|gif|png|wpf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx ...
```

Comment: You can get rid of some of the duplication in that regex: `(jpe?g|gif|png|wpf|docx?|xlsx? ...`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Server-side, "(?i)" can be used, but this doesn't work client-side. See [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100502214444/http://reflectedthought.com/thecoder/archive/2007/11/25/regularexpressionvalidator_ignore_case.aspx) for more discussion and workaround.

i.e. "...(?i)(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|wpf|..."

Comment: I can't reach that link. I actually get an 403.6... should I get worried?

Comment: @PEZ: retried, works fine... but there are plenty of others - just search +RegularExpressionValidator +IgnoreCase

Comment: I've tried that myself already. Doesn't help. It seems the server really has a problem with my IP!

Comment: The link in this answer is broken now. If someone has a good link to replace it with, please do so!

Answer (score 2):

In VisualBasic.NET, you can use the RegExOptions to ignore he case:

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("([^.]+[.](jpg|jpeg|gif))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, saw it too late. I should read the questions more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Regular Expression Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx), this should work:

```
// Added LowerCase i:
ValidationExpression="(?i:[^.]+[.](jpg|jpeg|gif|png|wpf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx ...
```

Comment: as long as it is server-side; I don't think it works client-side